# Como auto preencher uma coluna baseado no valor de outra coluna? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

tenho uma tabela de usuarios aonde possui as colunas: id_usuario, nome, id_empresa entre outros. E tenho outra tabela aonde salvo outras informações desse usuario, e tambem possuo as colunas nome e id_empresa, tem alguma forma de que ao adicionar o id_usuario na segunda tabela ela automaticamente puxe o valor dessas outras colunas da tabela principal? O id usuario é uma foreign key da tabela principal

Comment: Pesquise por JOIN.

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou confusa. No próprio banco você quer puxar os dados? Replicar?
Dê um exemplo claro da ideia em geral.

Comment: Era justamente o Join que eu precisava, sou novo na utilização de banco de dados e não conhecia a função. Precisava de uma função que retornasse os dados que estão relacionados pela chave estrangeira

Answer (score 0):

O join obtem o resultado que eu queria, retornando os valores relacionados pela chave estrangeira em duas tabelas distintas